# object has no attribute '_committed' error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want django automatically download and locally save image from image_url and "connect" it with image_file

how Upload image from an URL with Django
i have error
object has no attribute '_committed' error

```
from PIL import Image
import requests

url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jot2.png'
respone = requests.get(url, stream= True).raw
img = Image.open(respone)
img.save()

def home(request):
    Topic(title='hjb',content='vf',slug='fvrs',image=img,
            author=User.objects.first() )
            .save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save a file/image to an instance manually you should use the [`FileField.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) method, you can use a [`ContentFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class) to convert the raw data to a Django file object

```
import requests

def home(request):
    response = requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jot2.png', stream=True)
    topic = Topic(
        title='hjb',
        content='vf',
        slug='fvrs',
        author=User.objects.first()
    )
    topic.image.save('0jot2.png', ContentFile(response.content))
    topic.save()
```